# Checking PoDSecurityPolicy status in a GKE Cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-security

How to check if `PoDSecurityPolicy` is enabled on a `GKE` cluster  or not ? Using `gcloud container clusters describe <clustername>`, I could not find anything.

If I enable it on a cluster where this `plugin` is already enabled, it displays that the plugin has been enabled so there is no way actually to know that if `plugin` is already enabled on a cluster

```
 $ gcloud beta container clusters update mycluster --enable-pod-security-policy --zone us-east1-c
 Updating podsecpolicy-poc...done.
 Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<project>/zones/us-east1-c/clusters/mycluster].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`PodSecurityPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies) is still a **beta feature in GKE**, it can only be accessed by **GKE beta API**. To check if `PodSecurityPolicy` controller is enabled on your **GKE cluster**, run:

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters describe <cluster-name> --zone=<zone> --format json | jq '.podSecurityPolicyConfig'
```

Sample command with its result:

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters describe my-gke-cluster --zone=europe-west4-c --format json | jq '.podSecurityPolicyConfig'
{
  "enabled": true
}
```

#### Update:

When `PodSecurityPolicy` **is not enabled** on **GKE cluster**, the above query returns:

```
null
```

as there is no `podSecurityPolicyConfig` section available. You can also serch for it with `grep`. If `PodSecurityPolicy` **is enabled**, the result will look as follows:

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters describe my-gke-cluster --zone=europe-west4-c | grep -iA 1 podsecuritypolicy
podSecurityPolicyConfig:
  enabled: true
```

If **it is not**, you won't find this section at all.

Comment: It shows null when not enabled in a cluster .  `$ gcloud beta container clusters describe podsecpolicy-poc --zone us-east1-c --format json | jq '.podSecurityPolicyConfig'
null`

Comment: Yes, when it isn't `enabled`, there is no `podSecurityPolicyConfig` section, so the query returns `null`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mario for the detailed response. Is it enabled by default on new GKE Clusters ?

Comment: No, it is not enabled by default unless you enable it explicitly when creating your cluster. Refer to [this section](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies#enabling_podsecuritypolicy_controller) of the GCP docs.